# I'm not able to talk in chat, although I've already logged in

Tags: support, chat, login

I cannot chat with anyone.

I'm able to see all chatrooms but unable to chat. I tried clearing my browser's cache and history but still facing the same problem.  I've tried in multiple browsers, and all I got message like 'you must logged in to talk'

[image]

And I am getting the same message in the various browsers I've tried:

- Firefox 26.0
- Safari 6.0.2 (8536.26.17)
- Google Chrome Version 32.0.1700.107)

Comment: why i m downvoted..please tell me..

Comment: i added screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried logging in again? Click the link in the message, and tell us what happens.

Comment: yes,many times i logged in and then redirect to chat room with same problem..

Comment: I'm upvoting to rebalance people who downvote on guys seeking assistance.

Comment: thanks but i need solution also...@DavidKernin

Comment: If one of us *had* a solution, they would surely provide it. Anyway, I'll add a bounty to give your question visibility

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cookies too?

Comment: yes i cleared my all browsing data but same problem occure...@JourneymanGeek

Comment: I am also getting same issue in my account. When i am trying to search anything in the searchbox it gives an error. "Oops! Something Bad Happened![with cute cat on computer]-- It's not you, it's us. This is our fault."

Comment: This issue is not from client side it is from server side. I have also tried to open my login from another computer. but, same problem occurs. But, when i try to login in StackExchange it is working. I am getting problem in only StackOverflow chat application.

Comment: exactly i faced same problem but after 15-20 days,one day when i start my pc and i directly open http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ and i see that i logged in with chat room.so could try that.@danta

Comment: Is this an issue you're still facing now?

Comment: I have this issue also.